# Mysql Procedure INSERT (Already I looked at other answers)

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures

in mysql I have two tables: produto and dim_produto.

```
CREATE TABLE `produto` (
  `IdProduto` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Ativo` char(1) DEFAULT 'S',
  `CodPro` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `CodCat` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `DesPro` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `CodMar` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `CodSab` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `QtdCaixa` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `Transmitido` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdProduto`,`CodPro`),
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- 

CREATE TABLE `dim_produto` (
  `CodPro` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `Ativo` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CodCat` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Despro` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IdInc` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CodPro`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm trying to make a procedure that makes a select product in the table and enter the dim_produto table.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE dimProduto (codpro int (4), ativo char (1), codcat int (4), despro varchar (45))
BEGIN
insert into dim_produto (codpro, ativo, codcat, despro) (select codpro, ativo, codcat, despro from produto where transmitido = 'N');
END |
```

If I do this insert the way it is in the procedure, it works perfectly.

How do you call the procedure when I insert it in the select table dim_produto?
And how can I call it?

Grateful.

Comment: You are looking for a trigger, not a stored procedure:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html.

Comment: No ... Because I do not want to run when you have some event to a table.
I want the procedure to run when I run.

Comment: You can call the procedure using `call dimProduto (1, 'test', 2, ...)`. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @zedfoxus,  I want to perform the procedure without having to enter the values manually, want the procedure already see the data that will be inserted through select.
Something like:
call dim_produto (codpro,ativo,codcat,despro);
or
call dim_produto (select1, select2, select3, select4) ...

Comment: "see the data that will be inserted through the select".  Do you know how triggers work?  You are describing an  `insert` trigger on `produto`.

Comment: @zedfoxus, I know how the triggers work.
I want some columns of the product table are inserted into the dim_produto table, but I do not want them to be inserted after an event in the table product.
I want these columns are inserted by the time I desired.